# Debugging Visual Studio 2008 Web Application takes long to launch

Tags: visual-studio-2008, performance, debugging

When debugging an asp.net web application in VS2008 IDE, i feel it takes 'long' to launch the application because it my app is not big (about six pages).

I am not using the in-built VS web-server, I'm using the standard IIS web-server on my development machine. (That is, on the 'Start Options' dialog, I have set to 'Use custom server' and pointed 'Base URL' to the one I have defined in IIS)

I have not tried to fine-tune any options so I though someone can quickly point what needs to be changed to optmise this process

My machine is a P3 Duo-core and I feel it has sufficient memory for the job :)

Comment: I have the same problem, only it used to work fine until I installed the VS2011 beta.  Now VS2010 takes almost a minute to launch the site for debug when it used to take 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that's helped improve launch speed for me is to set up a separate AppPool and assign just the application you're trying to debug to that AppPool.

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to set up one. That will be grateful

Answer (score 0):

I would try turning off Indexing for the "temporary asp.net files" folder (located in your windows dir/microsoft.net/framework/%whatever version% folder).

Answer (score 0):

have you thought of intsalling service pack 1 (sp1)?  It can cause trouble but only in more complicated setups than what yours sounds like. It has performance improvments.
sp1 ~ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/products/cc533447.aspx

if you don't want to go for that there is a hotfix prior to that available here
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=10826